# Push Notfication is not working IOS7

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Hi in my application i have the Push Notification i have using the device token. I'm fetching the device token to my server and using the php code I'm sending the notification previously i have done the same process it was working fine now the notification is not working in my app.

In url its showing like this.

```
notifications sent!sending message:{ "aps" : { "alert" :"test", "badge" : 3, "sound" : "" } }nsending message:{ "aps" : { "alert" :"test", "badge" : 3, "sound" : "" } }nsending message:{ "aps" : { "alert" :"test", "badge" : 3, "sound" : "" } }n
```

My php code.

```
 <?php

 if($_POST['message']){

     include "db.php";

    $query = mysql_query("select * from notifi");
    $deviceToken = ARRAY();

   while ($row =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $deviceToken[] = $row["token"];
  }

    $message = stripcslashes($_POST['message']);

    $payload = '{
       "aps" :
      {
          "alert" :"'.$message.'",
          "badge" : 3,
          "sound" : ""

     }  
  }';
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx,'ssl', 'local_cert','ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx,'ssl','passphrase', 'ssvv');
   $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',$err,$errstr,60,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,$ctx);
   if(!fp){
      print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
       return;
   }else{
     print "notifications sent!";
   }
    $devArray = array();
    $devArray[] = $deviceToken;

     foreach($deviceToken as $token){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack("H*", str_replace(' ',' ',$token)).pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
      print "sending message:" .$payload . "n";
      fwrite($fp,$msg);
    }
   fclose($fp);
  }

?>
```

I have checked everything  its looking f9 but i not why its not working please tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information to go on, check your certificates. make sure that you are sending the push notification to the correct server (live or sandbox). And depending on the APNS version you are supporting read the response.

Comment: @rckoenes i have edited my question please check it

Comment: Did you check your certificates? is there any error from the SSL connect? Looks like you are testing with the development profile is the device token from a device running with a development profile and not AdHoc?

Comment: @rckoenes s im runing in development profile please tell how to check the ssl connect error

Comment: @rckoenes please tell me is it a code problem or certificate problem